# jquery datatables TableTools pdf file structure

Tags: jquery, datatables

I had used DataTales, tabletools to create the pdf file.
The pdf content is from the Table.

How can I add my own custom content to the pdf

Comment: you need the required columns to be exported ? is this what you looking for

Comment: Please show some code describing what you are trying to do.